# Using aar in Eclipse - why does the 3rd party activity resolve at build time but not run time?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, noclassdeffounderror, aar

I have a mature app that needs to have an SDK brought in that wraps the camera and makes it do some spiffy processing while it's running. The SDK has come to me in the form of some aar files but my app still lives in Eclipse. Because of my massive, steaming pile of a branding structure and deadlines for this integration the uncertain timeline required to fully migrate to Android Studio will not work (for now) so I'm going for converting the aars and using them in my app via Eclipse.

The problem I'm having is that I need to kick off the activity in the library but even though I fixed up all my build time reference problems, when running the app once I get to the point that is supposed to kick off the activity [I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK5R0.png).

I've read through and double checked dozens of how-tos explaining how to consume the aar files and I think I've followed every step including:

1. Unzip the aar files and dress them up as individual library projects, including the file structure with the resources, the manifest, and the .jar
2. Make the project that needs the libraries add them as such
3. Add the .jars contained in the library projects to the build path (this step was not listed in most articles, and wasn't necessary for the project to build, but nevertheless it did not help my problem)
4. Declare the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml that the library brings in and declares in its AndroidManifest.xml

As I've said, everything looks good at build time, so I'm not sure what else to check. Because I'm reading that Gradle and Android Studio mashes manifests together really well, I have a hunch that it's something I'm supposed to regulate between the manifests but I don't know what it could be if that is it. I've wondered if I'm declaring the 3rd party's activity properly, but I'm not sure how to test it because the only way I can think to test it is to provide gibberish for the namespace but even then there are no complaints. I've also tried dissecting the .apk to look at the .dex file but I could not decipher anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that our app had a bad version of the appcompat-v7 support library. The .jars in it were different sizes than the one that comes with the SDK and several resources were missing. I have no idea how we ended up that way or where this bad version came from. Once I replaced it, things went great.

Later, I did encounter the need to drop in the .so files into the libraries I made that came out of the .aar files as Stad Kurdziel said in his answer, but that was causing a different error (the exception explicitly states that the .so is missing) and I arrived at the solution independently.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the library may not be building properly in eclipse - even before it's being added as a dependency to the application project.

Try looking at `out/classes/*` and making sure you have a .class file for the activity in question.  I think the .class should actually be in the library as well as end up in the application project's `out/` dir also.

If there are any native files (x.so) (as I would imagine there might be for spiffy camera stuff), you can look for the x.so files being included in the `out/` dirs of both the library and application projects as well as the library.jar file.

Another option to maybe consider for this use case: https://github.com/ksoichiro/gradle-eclipse-aar-plugin

Comment: I managed to figure it out (see my answer) but you're right about the .so files being needed and it's unfortunate that many ".aar -> library" guides don't mention it.